# Adjust the height of landing to match the floor

Tags: wood, flooring, floor, stairs, carpentry

In an earlier post (since closed), I asked this community how to improve the appearance of a plywood floor. From the responses, I concluded that the best thing to do was to lay a legitimate flooring material on top of the plywood.

I have worked out all of the details of how I will do that and make it work with all of the existing elements of the project, except one: how to tie it in with the oak landing. The thickness of the flooring material that I will be using will be approximately 5/16 of the inch. What's a good way of tying in the landing with the rest of the floor. (I'm not included to cover the landing with the new flooring material. Also, note that the landing is one piece with the top cylinder along the axis of the staircase.

1. Should there be enough flexibility to simply lift the edge of the landing 5/16" to merge with the new floor?
2. Can the entire top step (i.e. the landing) be lifted 5/16" by inserting a spacer underneath the axial cylinder? Would that lead to an unacceptable discrepancy is step heights?
3. Can the two proposed approached be combined 50/50?
4. Any other suggestions?

[image]

Comment: How's the "one piece" area constructed?  Is the circle set around the column, or is the cap above the floor a separate piece?

Comment: The cap is a seperate piece. The landing and the cylinder below it are one piece.

Comment: The manufacturer or installer of the spiral staircase has surely answered this question for other customers. Have you asked them how to handle it?

Comment: i would just use transitions along the edge of the flooring where it meets the landing, leaving the whole landing as-is. The hard part will be the mitered corner of the transition, but it's a tiny area. Might be able to mix some woodglue and sawdust to fill in the inevitable tiny open miter crack. You might also need some nosing trim along the bottom-left edge where the plywood meets the cliff that is the stairwell. All that aside, the plywood actually looks great in the photo, consider leaving it.